# django: foreign key display

Tags: django, foreign-keys, displayobject

**My models:**

```
class ActsInformationModel(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    prelexRespProposId1=models.ForeignKey('RespProposModel', related_name='prelexRespProposId1', blank=True, null=True, default=None)

class RespProposModel(models.Model):
    respPropos=models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
```

**My view:**

```
...
dataDic["prelexRespProposId1"]=RespProposModel.objects.get(respPropos=respPropos)
print dataDic["prelexRespProposId1"].id #display 1 -> OK
dataDic["name"]="test"
act=ActsInformationModel.objects.get(...)
act.__dict__.update(dataDic)
print act.name #displays test
print "act.prelexRespProposId1", act.prelexRespProposId1 #display None -> PB
act.prelexRespProposId1=RespProposModel.objects.get(id=dataDic["prelexRespProposId1"].id)
print "act.prelexRespProposId1.id", act.prelexRespProposId1 #display 1 -> OK
```

Why do I have to do another query to get the value of the field ?
Other question, maybe related: why do I have to use the object to fill the foreign key field and not just an integer?

Comment: It is impossible to work out what this code is doing (why would you do `act.__dict__.update`, for example?) And why have you used such horrible unreadable attribute names?

Comment: Sorry for the names. act.__dict__.update takes all the key values of a dictionary (dataDic) and put them into the model instance act (the keys of the dictionary correspond to the name of the model fields). I am gonna add one more line, hope it will be better.

Comment: use `act.set(**dataDic), act.save()` instead

Comment: With act.set(**dataDic), I get the error 'ActsInformationModel' object has no attribute 'set'.

Comment: @rom put your solution in an answer below and accept it so the question is marked as solved.

Comment: Ok I just did it, but I have to wait two days to accept my own answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solved!**

When creating a foreign key, django saves the field with the original name + "_id".
So my field "prelexRespProposId1" was in fact named "prelexRespProposId1_id". I had to use the latter name to have my code working!

**My models:**

```
class ActsInformationModel(models.Model):
    prelexRespProposId1=models.ForeignKey('RespProposModel', related_name='prelexRespProposId1', blank=True, null=True, default=None)
```

**My view:**

```
...
dataDic["prelexRespProposId1_id"]=RespProposModel.objects.get(respPropos=respPropos)
print dataDic["prelexRespProposId1_id"].id #display 1 -> OK
act=ActsInformationModel.objects.get(...)
act.__dict__.update(dataDic)
print "act.prelexRespProposId1_id", act.prelexRespProposId1_id #display 1 -> Solved!!!
```